How do I fix autokey abbreviations?
Has anyone come across an issue where autokey abbreviations suddenly stop working? I don't have any errors to post even after running autokey-gtk --verbose in terminal. It appears autokey is pasting my most recent copy from the clip board rather than inserting the preset text when using the abbreviations. It worked perfectly for about 2 days and then broke. I'm running a Linux Kernel. Fedora 40
I'm expecting autokey to automatically replace the typed abbreviation with the preset text associated with it.
